# How to place an html element outside of a newly generated one

Tags: html, css, ionic2

Is it possible to place an Html element outside of a newly generated one?

Well, I have an IONIC2 app that generates a new element `<scroll-content>`, the issue is that this element has some CSS properties that affects the child elements.

So, what I would like to do it either to place that my `div` element outside of that `<scroll-content>` or even better to disable the CSS properties of `<scroll-content>` on the `div`

Here is the code, so I can make things clearer:

**HTML**

```
   <ion-content id="contentPadding">
     <div class="header">
     </div>
   </ion-content>
```

When Ionic renders the above code, the browser generate something like this:

**HTML**

```
   <ion-content id="contentPadding">
    <scroll-content>
     <div class="header">
     </div>
     <scroll-content>
   </ion-content>
```

CSS:

```
.top{
  background:black;
}

//generated

scroll-content{

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  will-change: scroll-position;
}
```

I guess, it's clearly shown that a new element called `<scroll-content>` is being created and `<div class="header">` inherits all the css properties of `<scroll-content>` which I would like to avoid in my case.

Comment: What CSS are you applying? Please provide your CSS. You could always override whatever you don't like by using `initial` to avoid inheritance, for example: `scroll-content .header { background-color: initial; }`

Comment: @Aziz I've added the CSS as you requested, please check it out and let me know

Comment: mind explaining the need for `position: absolute`? Do you have a live demo? It would be helpful to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, the CSS of `scroll-content` is generated from IONIC framework, and I don't have any control over it, that why I want to disable it. What I want to do is to fix   `<div class="header">` to the top; however ionic adds scrolling to any element inside ` <ion-content>` that's why so far I can't fix that header to the top of the view.

Comment: In that case why don't you use another element instead of `scroll-content`? Otherwise, simply override each rule to the default with CSS. For example: `scroll-content { position: static; overflow: visible; }`

Comment: I am not the one who create `scroll-content` so I can't control it

Comment: I tried to do `scroll-content { position: static; overflow: visible; }` however, it didn't work! what works only is to place the `div` element outside `scroll-content` and I can do that only when I do `inspect-element`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121079/discussion-between-aziz-and-james-runner).

Comment: @Aziz thanks for your time, I was finally able to solve it by disabling this property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` Basically, I overided `scroll-content` and by setting `webkit-overflow-scrolling` to `initial`

Answer (score 0):

Your header (child) is inheriting its parent's (scroll-content) CSS styling. You need to clear any unwanted inherited rules by explicitly changing the inherited styles. For example, if you want to reset the css-display, write

```
.header {
   display: initial;
}
```

Hopefully in the future we can avoid this with [the all:initial](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand) trick - however, it currently isn't [supported enough.](http://caniuse.com/#search=all)

Comment: The `position` property isn't really inherited.

Comment: You're right, I chose a bad example. Fixing it now, thank you.